# Scrapy - How to avoid Pagination Blackhole?

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy, web-crawler

I was recently working on a website spider and noticed it was requesting an infinite number of pages because a site hadn't coded their pagination to ever stop.

So while they only had a few pages of content, it still would generate a next link and a url ...?page=400, ...?page=401, etc.

The content didn't change, just the URL. Is there a way to make Scrapy stop following pagination when content stops changing? Or something I could code up custom.

Comment: You will need to keep track of something that changes and stop when it does not anymore, ie the page title or a headline showing the results (you could analyze the text via an xpath query obviously).

Comment: But how would I link that to a URL that it is about to scrape and prevent the LinkExtractor from  using it? Integrating this into CrawlSpider is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content doesn't change you can compare the content of the current page with the previous page and if it's the same, break the crawl.

for example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    product_urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
    # check last page
    if response.meta.get('prev_urls') == product_urls:
        logging.info('reached the last page at: {}'.format(response.url))
        return  # reached the last page
    # crawl products
    for url in product_urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse_product)
    # create next page url
    next_page = response.meta.get('page', 0) + 1
    next_url = re.sub('page=\d+', 'page={}'.format(next_page), response.url)
    # now for the next page carry some data in meta
    yield Request(next_url, 
                  meta={'prev_urls': product_urls,
                        'page': next_page}
```

Comment: Mixing `yields` and `return` would not work, but the general idea to limiting to product links is insteresting. Also, might as well test `response.meta.get('prev_urls') == product_urls` before yielding product `Request` objects.

Comment: @paultrmbrth Thanks, moved the check at the beginning. Though mixing return and yield works fine in python2 as long as `return` doesn't return anything, it just acts like `break` here.

Comment: Would this be possible to use with a crawlspider, and a link extractor? Or is this for a default Scrapy spider?

Comment: @JimFactor This is for default `scrapy.Spider`. I bet something can definitely be hacked together with Downloader middlewares if you want to use it CrawlSpider. Maybe check for products in every response and cache it, if products on some page are already in cache then that could be an indication of pagination and you can raise CloseSpider exception to stop the crawl. Scrapy is super flexible so there's probably at least few ways of doing something. You can always open up a new issue and maybe someone has already did this before :)